# Reconstructing k-means using pre-computed cluster centres

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, k-means

I'm using k-means for clustering with number of clusters 60. Since, some of the clusters are coming out as meaning less, I've deleted those cluster centers from cluster center array(count = 8) and saved in `clean_cluster_array`.

This time, I'm re-fitting k-means model with `init = clean_cluster_centers`. and `n_clusters = 52` and `max_iter = 1` because i want to avoid re-fitting as much as possible.

The basic idea is to recreate new model with `clean_cluster_centers` . The problem here is since, we are removing large number of clusters; The model is quickly configuring to more stable centers even with `n_iter = 1`. Is there any way to recreate k-means model?

Comment: Could you show what clean_cluster_array looks like and what clusters_centers_ looks like after you fit again?

Comment: I cannot show it here as the centers are of shape (52, 2E5). They are different to answer your question.

Comment: @ValentinCalomme I think what you are suggesting is feeding `clean_cluster_array` 
to `clusters_centers_`  after fitting the model, this should rewrite the centers. Although, I would like to bypass this model fitting altogether. I'll try this out and post the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've fitted a KMeans object, it has a `cluster_centers_` attribute. You can directly update it by doing something like this:

`cls.cluster_centers_ = new_cluster_centers`

So if you want a new object with the clean cluster centers, just do something like the following:

```
cls = KMeans().fit(X)
cls2 = cls.copy()
cls2.cluster_centers_ = new_cluster_centers
```

And now, since the predict function only checks that your object has a non-null attribute called cluster_centers_, you can use the predict function

```
def predict(self, X):
    """Predict the closest cluster each sample in X belongs to.

    In the vector quantization literature, `cluster_centers_` is called
    the code book and each value returned by `predict` is the index of
    the closest code in the code book.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape = [n_samples, n_features]
        New data to predict.

    Returns
    -------
    labels : array, shape [n_samples,]
        Index of the cluster each sample belongs to.
    """
    check_is_fitted(self, 'cluster_centers_')

    X = self._check_test_data(X)
    x_squared_norms = row_norms(X, squared=True)
    return _labels_inertia(X, x_squared_norms, self.cluster_centers_)[0]
```